# hIn drupal How to set input field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, hidden

I have a hidden input field as below:

```
<div id="field-journal-results-add-more-wrapper">
    <input name="field_journal_results[ind][0][value]" value="" type="hidden">
</div>
```

How to set this hidden input field? 
I have tried using custom jQuery module but it didn't work.

```
drupe_add_j("j Query(document)ready(function () { var text = $('field-content a')text();$('input[name='field_journal_results[ind][0][value]']')val(text);}   });", "inline");
```

Please suggest an alternative way to set Drupal entity hidden value.

Comment: `drupe_add_j` ..... `"j Query(document)ready`....please revise your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right syntaxe : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document)ready(function () { var text = $('field-content a')text();$('input[name='field_journal_results[ind][0][value]']')val(text);}   });", "inline");
```

But i recommand to you to add js in javascript file in custom module and call it like this :

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module_name').'/js/customjsfile.js');
```